# Is this an example of an Enum (Enumerated Type)

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, ddl, enum

I'm looking at a code base that I have inherited. I'm new to Postgres (but have an Oracle background), and I think this in one of the queries is an example of an enum. Can someone confirm if I'm correct in this thinking, and if not then what this is, and how I find out more about it.

```
SELECT fp.id AS fund_part_id, fp.fund_id, fp.principle_amount, fp.detail
FROM finance.fund_part fp
WHERE fp.status = 'live'::finance.fund_part_status;
```

I can see if the pg_enum catalog (table) that there are a series of records that belong to one `enumtypid oid`. Some of the entries in the `enumlabel name` column are `['live', 'for sale', 'pre-agrement']`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like `finance.fund_part_status` is an enum type.

Assuming you're using the `psql` command-line interpreter, try this command:

```
\dT+ finance.fund_part_status;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out for sure with this query to the system catalog table `pg_type`:

```
SELECT typtype
FROM   pg_type
WHERE  oid = 'finance.fund_part_status'::regtype
```

I quote [the manual about `pg_type`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-type.html):

> typtype is b for a base type, c for a composite type (e.g., a table's
>   row type), d for a domain, **e for an enum type**, p for a pseudo-type, or
>   r for a range type. See also typrelid and typbasetype.

Bold emphasis mine.
More about the cast to `regtype` in the chapter about [object identifier types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html).